# Android: How to consolidate multiple notification icons in android

Tags: android, notifications, icons

I am writing an application where I am pushing notifications to the client from the server. If server pushes many notification messages to the user, I see that there are multiple app notification icons in the notification bar(where there are other icons such as battery, connectivity etc) are displayed.
I want to limit it one but I still want to retain notifications in the notification drawer(in pull down pane).

I tried canceling notificationManager.cancel(int id), but it removes notification from the the notification drawer along with notification bar. Is there any extra flag or any api to get around this?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at Stack Your notifications section: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html  You are not supposed to create multiple separate notifications in the pull-down menu it is against the android design guidelines.

Comment: It might be the case that this goes against the guidelines, but I am writing an app for my own personal use where notifications are used as reminders to do various tasks, so I really want many notifications in my drawer (so I can swipe away the relevant notification when I do the task) but only one icon in my bar. Is this even possible? If not then how am I supposed to implement what I want? Is there another way of thinking about it? A key point of my app is that I get distinct notifications for distinct TODO tasks: I really don't want one "stacked" notification in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

You can update the notification content. Here are the docs to do it http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating

This is what the SMS/Whatsapp/gmail does. If there's only one message, they display it's content, otherwise they would display the amount of unread messages and or the number of people who wrote them. The point is that they only have one notification on the status bar, and they keep using the same one until the user goes in the app.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, this is strictly speaking against the android design guidelines. However guidelines are not always right in every situation, and it seems to me that may be possible to do this, at least for some versions of Android.

In 4.4 and 6.0 (I didn't test other versions) some testing seems to indicate that if the notification priority is set to PRIORITY_MIN then the icon will not appear in the notification bar but it will appear in the drawer.

I do not know whether this behaviour is guaranteed though and the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#PRIORITY_MIN) seem a bit vague. There is also an annoying consequence that the position of the notification in the drawer is affected by this, so this answer is not at all ideal.

I wish there were a better solution for people who actively choose to not follow the guidelines because of specific design requirements.